# Make a base64 URL with AdvancedCustomFields plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the AdvancedCustomFields WordPress plugin, and I want to make a URL that comes out of this field, URL base64:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author-link', true); ?>
```

The example link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-oxmQxNBeQ

It should show on post: `aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cueW91dHViZS5jb20vd2F0Y2g/dj11LW94bVF4TkJlUQ==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply encode the string with [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) like below.

```
<?php echo base64_encode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author-link', true)); ?>
```

Comment: thanks dude, its work!

Comment: one more bro: <a herf="<?php echo base64_encode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author-link1', true)); ?>&opl=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author-link', true); ?>&utb=<?php echo base64_encode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author-link3', true)); ?>" target="blank"></a>